# Setting up a HUDL as a debugging device?

Tags: android, debugging, tablet

I'm using an ASUS X75VC laptop running Windows 8.1 and am trying to enable application debugging on my Tesco HUDL running Android 4.2.2. I have been trying and failing different techniques for the last few hours so decided I will post to see if anyone else can pinpoint the problem.

I've checked the following;

- My Android project is set to use 4.2.2 as the API.
- My HUDL has developer mode turned on and allows the use of non-market applications.
- When plugged in my HUDL displays the messages;

  - "Connected as a media device".
  - "USB Debugging connected".

However, using the command "adb.exe devices" does not list my device, and attempting to run the project while manually selecting a device doesn't display my device in the list.

I have searched for drivers on ASUS website however am not completely sure what I'm looking for as the results I had been shown were all to do with graphics card updates and such, no USB.

If anyone can help me it will be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Since posting this I have also tried changing the HUDL connection to PTP instead of an MTP media device and still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to Control Panel > Device Manager.
2. Check that there is an exclamation mark next to Other Devices > ADB Interface, meaning that the driver is not installed.
3. For the ADB Interface, select Update Driver > Browse my computer for driver software > Let me pick from a list of... > Have Disk... > Enter the path to your Android SDK USB driver folder (ie. C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver).
4. Ignore the warning and complete the installation.

Answer (score 1):

I got my hudl to work as a debug device on android studio with windows 10.

First you have to enable developer options (use google). Then connect as a media device.

It the appears as a connectable device wen yo run the app in android studio. You have to enable debugging on your hudl notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my hudl 2 to work with a good bit of messing about. some of these steps may not be necessary but in the end i got the hudl debugging

- Connect the Hudl via usb
- On the Hudl change its connection mode from media device to camera
- Download and install the following stuff  https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-usb-driver-for-android-devices
- Open the device manager and look in Other Devices
- Right Click the ADB device and update driver
- Select Browse computer for driver
- Click let me pick from a list of devices
- Select the Samsung device driver

Remove and reconnect the hudl  via usb. the hudl should then have a popup asking for you to accept connections via the pc. allow it and your hudl should then be available for debugging

I was debugging through Xamarin studio at the time